# Imgur API: Dictionary values magically turns into None?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, imgur

I know voodoo magic probably isn't the cause of this - but it sure seems like it!

I have the following code snippets, making use of the imgur API. The `imgur` object is the client which the imgur API uses and contains an attribute `credits` which displays the number of access credits the user has on the website.

```
imgur = imgurpython.ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)
```

Calling:

```
imgur.credits
```

Returns the credits as normal, i.e.:

```
{'ClientLimit': 12500, 'UserReset': 1503185179, 'UserLimit': 500, 'UserRemaining': 0, 'ClientRemaining': 12000}
```

However when I attempt to call the dictionary in a later function:

```
def check_credits(imgur):
    '''
        Receives a client - and if there is not much credits left,
        wait until the credit refills - i.e. pause the program
    '''
    credits = imgur.credits
    credits_remaining = credits['UserRemaining']
    reset_time = credits['UserReset']

    if credits_remaining < 10:
        print('not enough credits, remaining: %i' % credits_remaining)
        now = int(dt.utcnow().timestamp())
        wait_time = reset_time - now
        print('waiting for: %i' % wait_time)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

***Sometimes*** the values in the dictionaries seem to turn into `None` instead of the integers they are supposed to be. In this case both `reset_time` and `credits_remaining` sometimes turn out to be `None`. In order to allow my code to run I'm having to add try-catches all over the code and it's getting quite frustrating. By the way, this function is called whenever the error `ImgurClientRateLimitError`, which is when `imgur.credits['UserRemaining'] == 0`. I'm wondering if anyone know why this may have been the case.

Comment: Can't help you with why they return `None`, but why add `try/except` everywhere?  Just check for `None` when you first assign those variables, and substitute an appropriate dummy value at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon looking at the source code for the client it seems that this is updated automatically upon each request. The updated values are obtained from the response headers after a call to `ImgurClient.make_request`. The header values are obtained from `dict.get` which can return None if the key does not exist in the headers dictionary. The code for reference is here: https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython/blob/master/imgurpython/client.py#L143

I am not sure if these headers are still used on errors like 404 or 403 but I would investigate further from there. It seems though that because of this behavior you would need to either cache previous values or manually call the ImgurClient.get_credits method in these cases to get the real values. Whichever fix you go with is up to you.